# OpenMP on single core

Tags: c, performance, openmp, cpu-usage

Can I to use OpenMP on a machine with a single core cpu? There will be some improvement in the performance?

Answer (score 3):

Yes, you can. You can annotate the code with OpenMP directives and still run the application sequentially. For that, you have to compile and run the application without the OpenMP flag (`e.g.,` `-fopenmp`).

You can use OpenMP on a single core and still have a performance improvement by, for instance, running a multithreaded program in a single-core CPU with hyper-threading.

There are memory-bound algorithms that take advantage of hyper-threading because during execution some threads will be still waiting for memory to be fetched, while other threads will be doing computation. In rare cases, the gains by hyper-threading can come from an improvement in branch prediction.

Nevertheless, most often than not, using OpenMP with a single core will slow down your application even with a single thread, because of the overhead intrinsic to the OpenMP directives. Moreover, threads are also "fighting" for the same resources.

Answer (score 1):

You might gain an advantage where a program has both I/O bound and CPU bound portions...if thread '1' is I/O bound then thread '2' can do its CPU bound stuff.. This becomes even more noticeable if the program is very heavy on I/O for portions of its execution

Comment: as long as the threads do not actually need the same I/O and fight for it of course